# Sort attributes in Add XML step in Kettle

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle

I'm creating a XML using Kettle but i can't sort attributes in an element. Sorting elements works fine, but attributes are only sorted alphabetically.

[image: [Example]

The xml generated: `<Transaction DraftTransactionFlag="N" EntryDateTime="" EntryLaneID="" EntryLaneSeqNo="" ..../>`

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is your issue? what do you want to achieve? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I'm trying to set a specific order defined by me of the attributes inside an element. The Spoon step "Add XML" orders the attributes alphabetically by default, and I can't change that.

Comment: If it is not allowing you to sort on add XML level, you can try explicit sorting, use sort-rows step to sort according to your requirement.